# Modify Table in VirtueMart 2 Shopping Cart & Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla2.5, virtuemart

I'm using Virtuemart 2 and Joomla 2.5

I would like to modify the table such as removing the columns SKU, Only, and Dicount, etc.

How can I do so? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be accomplished with a simple template override (never thought I would say that about VM!!!)

First you need to copy this file:

```
/JOOMLA INSTALL/components/com_virtuemart/views/cart/tmpl/default_pricelist.php
```

Put that copy here:

```
/JOOMLA INSTALL/templates/YOUR TEMPLATE/html/com_virtuemart/cart/default_pricelist.php
```

Then it is a matter of removing the code you don't want to display from the copied file.